# Treat question marks as part of url in Flask route

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a route that echoes whatever is passed to a url parameter.  If I pass something that contains a question mark, such as `/question/What is faster than a speeding bullet?` in a browser, the echoed value does not contain the question mark or anything after it.  Flask is truncating the value because it expects query parameters to follow the question mark.  How can I capture a url value that includes a question mark?

```
@app.route('/question/<value>')
def read_question(value):
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I can see:

- ignore non-alphanumeric text, compressing them into `-` (see: Stack Overflow question URLS)
- percent-encode the question mark as %3F. This is probably horrible and fraught with potential errors.